# Node Express.js - Download file from memory - 'filename must be a string'

Tags: node.js, express, download

I'm trying to package data in memory into a text file and send it to the user, triggering a file download.

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/download', function(request, response){

    fileType = request.query.fileType;
    fileName = ( request.query.fileName + '.' + fileType ).toString();
    fileData = request.query.fileData;

    response.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName );
    response.set('Content-type', 'text/plain');

    var fileContents = new Buffer(fileData, "base64");

    response.status(200).download( fileContents );

});
```

It keeps throwing an error saying that Content-disposition's filename parameter must be a string. fileName is most certainly a string, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: which line gives error?

Comment: Please declare your local variables such as `fileType`, `fileName` and `fileData` with `let`.  Using accidental globals in a server is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: If you look at the [code for `res.download()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L514), you can see that it just calls `res.sendFile()` so it is only built to send data from a file, not from memory.  You will have to find a different way to send directly from memory or write to a temporary file first.

Comment: instead of using res.download() you should use res.send(Buffer) and it would work

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Update:

Thanks to @jfriend00's advice, it is better and more efficient to directly send Buffer to client as file, instead of saving it first in server disk.

To implement, `stream.PassThrough()` and `pipe()` can be used, here is an example:

```
var stream = require('stream');
//...
app.get('/download', function(request, response){
  //...
  var fileContents = Buffer.from(fileData, "base64");
  
  var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  readStream.end(fileContents);

  response.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
  response.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

  readStream.pipe(response);
});
```

---

According to Express [document](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.download), `res.download()` API is:

> **res.download(path [, filename] [, fn])**
>
> Transfers the file at path as an “attachment”. Typically, browsers will prompt the user for download. By default, the Content-Disposition header “filename=” parameter is path (this typically appears in the browser dialog). Override this default with the filename parameter.

Please note the first parameter of `res.download()` is a "path", which indicates the path of file in server that would be downloaded. In your code, the first parameter is a Buffer, that's why Node.js complain that "filename parameter must be a string" -- By default, the `Content-Disposition` header “filename=” parameter is *path*.

To make your code work using `res.download()`, you need to save the `fileData` in server as a file, and then invoke `res.download()` with that file's path:

```
var fs = require('fs');
//...
app.get('/download', function(request, response){
  //...
  var fileContents = Buffer.from(fileData, "base64");
  var savedFilePath = '/temp/' + fileName; // in some convenient temporary file folder
  fs.writeFile(savedFilePath, fileContents, function() {
    response.status(200).download(savedFilePath, fileName);
  });
});
```

Also, please note `new Buffer(string[, encoding])` is deprecated now. It is better to use `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])`.

Comment: There should be a way to solve this problem without first writing the data to a file.  Also, your code doesn't generate a unique filename that won't conflict with other requests and doesn't clean up the temporary file at an appropriate time.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right. Write data to a file and eventually delete it is not efficient. I'm looking for a better solution, any suggestions?

Comment: @jfriend00 I've found a better solution which does not need saving-file-in-server. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: > I've found a better solution which does not need saving-file-in-server

What was your solution @shaochuancs?

Comment: Hi, @Maksim, please check the "update" of this answer.

Comment: @shaochuancs Thank you very much! One question, the fileData variable is an array and fileName is a string?

Comment: @user1584421 fileData variable is a string. Please note the API `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])`

Comment: It works, but the text is all gibberish! Maybe it's because it's Base64? Thank you for your creativity and help!

Comment: This works. But how to implement the client side to enable a file download from the buffer string sent from the server via Ajax?

Comment: Rollback to revision 4. For Ratan Uday Kumar's edit, it's just misc words change, and he modified the words referenced from Express document, which should not happen.

Comment: Rollback to revision 4. For Alex_swordz's edit, the revision 4 code snippet is used to indicate how to send Buffer, based on the code example from OP's question. It is better to keep `fileName` as it is -- in OP's question, `fileName` is retrieved from `request.query`, which has already handled URI encoding.

Answer (score 23):

```
app.get('/download', (request, response) => {
  const fileData = 'SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ=='
  const fileName = 'hello_world.txt'
  const fileType = 'text/plain'

  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`,
    'Content-Type': fileType,
  })

  const download = Buffer.from(fileData, 'base64')
  response.end(download)
})
```

Comment: You maybe having buffer only so put download as request.file, and you are good to go. I was looking for this for an hour now :) Thanks a lot

Comment: not working... I am getting `Hello, World!` in response but chrome is not opening the save file popup ...also not saving files automatically...

Answer (score -3):

I found this question via google. My problem was, that I wanted to send a generated `index.html` file directly from the memory, instead of writing it to the file system first.

This is how it works:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //set the appropriate HTTP header
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    //send it to the client
    res.send('<h1>This is the response</h1>');
});
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032538