# Node.js Can't set headers after they are sent Error after introducing res.render()

Tags: javascript, node.js, header, request-headers, response-headers

I have this snippet of code:

```
   app.post('/pst', function(req, res) {
            var data = req.body.convo;

            res.render('waiting.ejs');  //ADDED THIS

            myFunc(data).then(result => {


            res.render('success.ejs');  //THEN THIS

            //---------------------------------
            //clever way to send text file to client from the memory of the server
            var fileContents = Buffer.from(result, 'ascii');
            var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
            readStream.end(fileContents);
            res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            readStream.pipe(res);
            //--------------------------------------

            }).catch( .....
```

The code i commented as 'clever way to send file from memory of the server' comes from this post:
[Node Express.js - Download file from memory - 'filename must be a string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922074/node-express-js-download-file-from-memory-filename-must-be-a-string/45922316?noredirect=1#comment90583415_45922316)

What this does is is takes a string from the memory and serves it to the client as a .txt file.

This code used to work.

Then i decided to add the `res.render('waiting.ejs');` line and i got this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I then experimented with adding another res.render() [in this case `res.render('success.ejs');`] before and after the code tht sends the .txt file to the client.

The error remained. Also, there is no redirect to success.ejs, in other words the `res.render('success.ejs');` never worked, despite whether it is placed before ofr after that piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   app.post('/pst', function(req, res) {
            var data = req.body.convo;

            myFunc(data).then(result => {


          

            //---------------------------------
            //clever way to send text file to client from the memory of the server
            var fileContents = Buffer.from(result, 'ascii');
            var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
            readStream.end(fileContents);
            res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            readStream.pipe(res);
             res.redirect(`/success`);  //THEN THIS
            //--------------------------------------

            }).catch( .....
```

When you add middleware to  express (which is built on connect) using the app.use method, you're appending items to `Server.prototype.stack` in connect.
 When the server gets a request, it iterates over the stack, calling the (request, response, next) method.

The problem is, if in one of the middleware items writes to the response body or headers (it looks like it's either/or for some reason), but doesn't call `response.end()` and you call `next()` then as the core Server.prototype.handle method completes, it's going to notice that:

```
there are no more items in the stack, and/or
that response.headerSent is true.
```

So, it throws an error. But the error it throws is just this basic response (from the connect http.js source code:

```
res.statusCode = 404;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.end('Cannot ' + req.method + ' ' + req.url);
```

The problematic middleware sets the response header without calling `response.end()` and calls next(), which confuses express's server.
so you set the header through `res.render()` .Now if you will try to render again it will throw you an error.

```js
   

app.get('/success',(req,res)=> {
   res.render("container/index",{waiting:"waiting",......});
  //handle your task then in client side index.ejs with appropriate setTimeout(()=>{},2000) for the waiting div , show waiting div for 2 seconds
});
 //then your actual success gets render
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So the modifications you provided will allow me to run the res.redirect('success.ejs'); line?  But what about the   res.render('waiting.ejs');  line?

Comment: you can handle only one render per middleware of response

Comment: Just a message and an animation

Comment: you can add those 2 additional routes , it will make ur work done ....and see the above code too

Comment: I wanted after the POST these two routes to be run. With the updated method, i am not sure how both these two routes will be renered AFTER the POST

Comment: @user1584421 it will work try it , but u have to make your animation and waiting message in normal ejs file, you can't render and redirect at the same time . my above answer is valid. try and ping me for upcoming errors

Comment: But in your code you write 
app.get('/waiting',(req,res)=>{
  res.redirect('/success');

The waiting.ejs file never gets called

Comment: I tried using res.redirect() but on the browser a message "Cannot GET /waiting.ejs" is displayed.

Comment: You need to add a workaround for that , I searched b but there is no way to do res.render() and res.redirect() at the same place.. because the header are already set and sent my res.render()..

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check express.js source code ([here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/response.js#L985)):

```
res.render = function render(view, options, callback) {
  var app = this.req.app;
  var done = callback;
  var opts = options || {};
  var req = this.req;
  var self = this;

  // support callback function as second arg
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    done = options;
    opts = {};
  }

  // merge res.locals
  opts._locals = self.locals;

  // default callback to respond
  done = done || function (err, str) {
    if (err) return req.next(err);
    self.send(str);
  };

  // render
  app.render(view, opts, done);
};
```

You can see that when You use `res.render()` method, it will pass the done callback to `app.render(...)` ([source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/application.js#L531)), it will then pass `done` to `tryInitView` etc.

At the end, it will invoke `done` callback with `str` in case of success or `err` in case of failure. It then triggers `res.send()` inside `done` callback which simply blocks You from setting headers after that.

Comment: Thanks! So is there a workaround that, or i will just have to forget using the res.render()s if i want to send the txt file to the client?

Answer (score 1):

res.render() function compiles your template, inserts locals there, and creates html output out of those two things. that's why error comes.
don't use it twice coz it send response.