# NodeJS Express — Serve generated index.html public file without saving it

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, server, code-generation

When using express, the expectation is that you'll serve a public directory.

```
const app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('./public/'));
```

Is there a way I could serve a *generated* file instead? For my application, it would be much more convenient if I could build the index.html directly, then serve that 'file' directly from memory, without having to save it just to then serve it via 'use'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the expectation is that you'll serve a public directory

I don't think that is the expectation at all. Many applications just use routes instead making a REST micro service.

There are two ways you can do what you want to do.

1. Use a templating engine with NodeJS and just `res.render()` the template. [Check this out](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) for more information, even though the article is using `.pug` you can use [these ones](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) as well. Popular ones are ejs, handlebars

   ```
   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
   })
   ```
2. Or you can write everything inside `res.send()` for example:

   ```
   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       //set the appropriate HTTP header
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

       //send multiple responses to the client
       res.send('<h1>This is the response</h1>');
   });
   ```

Comment: I'm looking for something similar with forking a child process; directly pass the module instead of a filepath. If you can help with that too, I'd greatly appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048262/nodejs-fork-child-process-with-function-string-instead-of-file